# How to get the user which added the bot?

Tags: discord.js

i'm currently working on a Discord.js bot and i want that i get the id or name of the user which added the bot to the guild.

I want that the person which added the bot gets a DM.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => { // This event fires when a guild is created or when the bot is added to a guild.
    guild.fetchAuditLogs({type: "BOT_ADD", limit: 1}).then(log => { // Fetching 1 entry from the AuditLogs for BOT_ADD.
        log.entries.first().executor.send(`Thank you for adding me to ${guild.name}!`).catch(e => console.error(e)); // Sending the message to the executor.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!